# Reading an binary .fbx file in golang

Tags: go

Unlike in other languages, I really couldn't figure out how to read a binary file into an array of bytes or just turn it into an ASCII-string, which puts me into quite a problem.

The code I've been using:

```
func TestFBX(fileName string) {
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var content []byte
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text := []byte(scanner.Text())
        buf := bytes.NewReader(text)
        err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &content)

        if (err != nil) {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", content)
    fmt.Println("")

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

What it does in the end is print out [ ], an empty slice.
Now when I tried putting float64 or int32 instead of []byte it did print out different numbers but I still honestly don't get how to read the **whole file** and not just whatever number is there at the beginning.

Comment: `Scanner` is specifically geared toward scanning through text bit by bit, pretty much the opposite of what you're trying to do. I think you're just making this more complicated than it needs to be. Take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still interested in golang FBX reader here is my implementation https://github.com/o5h/fbx. Not well tested, but should work.

Internally FBX have following structure:

```
type Header [27]byte
type FBX struct {
  Header *Header
  Top    *Node
  Nodes  []*Node
}
type Node struct {
  EndOffset       uint32
  NumProperties   uint32
  PropertyListLen uint32
  NameLen         uint8
  Name            string
  Properties      []*Property
  NestedNodes     []*Node
 }
 type Property struct {
  TypeCode byte
  Data     interface{}
 }
```

Here is an usage example:

```
f, _ := os.Open("cube.fbx")
defer f.Close()
fbxData, _ := fbx.ReadFrom(f)
ibo := fbxData.Filter(fbx.FilterName("PolygonVertexIndex"))[0]
fmt.Println(ibo)
```

Output will be

```
[0 2 -4 7 5 -5 4 1 -1 5 2 -2 2 7 -4 0 7 -5 0 1 -3 7 6 -6 4 5 -2 5 6 -3 2 6 -8 0 3 -8]
```

Here is an example, how I get other attributes

```
ibo := node.FilterName("PolygonVertexIndex")[0].Properties[0].AsInt32Slice()
vbo := node.FilterName("Vertices")[0].Properties[0].AsFloat64Slice()
normals := node.FilterName("Normals")[0].Properties[0].AsFloat64Slice()
uvIndex := node.FilterName("UVIndex")[0].Properties[0].AsInt32Slice()
uv := node.FilterName("UV")[0].Properties[0].AsFloat64Slice()

numFaces := len(ibo) / 3
for f := 0; f < numFaces; f++ {
    face := &Face{}

    index := f * 3
    a := int(ibo[index+0])
    b := int(ibo[index+1])
    c := int(ibo[index+2])*-1 - 1

    face.a.Position = getVec3(vbo, a)
    face.b.Position = getVec3(vbo, b)
    face.c.Position = getVec3(vbo, c)

    uva := int(uvIndex[index+0])
    uvb := int(uvIndex[index+1])
    uvc := int(uvIndex[index+2])
    face.a.UV = getVec2(uv, uva)
    face.b.UV = getVec2(uv, uvb)
    face.c.UV = getVec2(uv, uvc)

    face.a.Normal = getVec3(normals, f*3+0)
    face.b.Normal = getVec3(normals, f*3+1)
    face.c.Normal = getVec3(normals, f*3+2)

    faces[f] = face
}

type Vec3 struct {
    X, Y, Z float32
}
type Vec2 struct {
    X, Y float32
}
type Vertex struct {
    Position *Vec3
    Normal   *Vec3
    Color    *Vec3
    UV       *Vec2
}

type Face struct {
    a vertex.Vertex
    b vertex.Vertex
    c vertex.Vertex
}

func getVec3(data []float64, index int) *Vec3 {
    i := index * 3
    x := float32(data[i])
    y := float32(data[i+1])
    z := float32(data[i+2])
    return &Vec3{x, y, z}
}
```

Comment: How did you define `Face` and what did `getVec3` do?

Answer (score 3):

You might just want [`ioutil.ReadFile(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile)?:

```
import "io/ioutil"

// ...

bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./myfile.fbx")
if err != nil {
  panic(err) // TODO: handle error?
}
// now "bs" has all the bytes in the file...
fmt.Printf("OK: read %d byte(s)\n", len(bs))
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the question title and the question content does not match up and leads to different interpretations of what the author desires. The content of this stack overflow question reveals how little of the surrounding context the author understands with what they are asking.

The FBX file format is a binary/text spec designed for 3D models/animation. The official way to read in file format is provided by Autodesk through an [SDK they provide](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2019-0).

Reading in byte data from a file is extremely simple in golang and they provide said functionality through a single liner, being [ioutil.ReadFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile). The fact that the author stated: "Unlike in other languages, I really couldn't figure out how to read a binary file into an array of bytes", leads me to believe they failed to use google before ever opening the question.

As for interpreting an FBX file, the accepted answer links to a personal library that panics for even simple FBX files. Creating these importers are hard because the FBX spec is extremely generic and allows for extensions to the format for vendor-specific functionality. For further explanation, I would suggest reading [Blender's write up](https://code.blender.org/2013/08/fbx-binary-file-format-specification/) as to what they have learned from exploring the format.